# How do you tell a neural network's layer to look for/at specific traits such as eyes, and edges?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, classification

In an face recognition image classification, I understand that each layer looks at different key aspects of the image?

For example, layer-1 might look at the edges, and layer-2 might look at the colors, and layer-3 might look at the eyes, etc...

Each layer has an activation function, and takes the output from the previous layer as input.

How do you specifically tell a layer to look for a specific trait in the image?
How do you know what each layer is looking for?

Comment: As far I know, the way we 'tell' a neural network to look for a specific trait is by giving it data that enforces the fact that the given trait is a good metric for the classification we are trying to achieve.... That is we can't explicitly ask it to look for a trait... we can hope that it picks the desired trait on its own based on what it sees in the data...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To know what features of the input image a layer of deep CNN is looking for, you can obtain the filters and filter activations/ feature maps of that layer and visualize them by plotting color-maps of the activations and kernel weights. Though we can visualize the activations of a layer and infer what the filter might be looking for, it is rather hard to enforce a network's layer to learn specific traits as the weights are randomly initialized  before training such that any filter of the network might choose to learn any random specific feature of the input image.